# Как перевести массив из PHP в JS?

Tags: php, javascript

Здравствуйте. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться, у меня есть массив в **php**:

```
<?php
$credit=array(
    array('Номер 1','10','03'),
    array('Номер N','N','N'),
    array('Номер 10','6','12')
    );                                                                      
?>

var credit_m_m = <?php echo json_encode($credit_m_m);?>;
```

Массив из **php** мне нужно перевести в **js**, как указано в примере ниже:

```
var options = {                                                 
     manualInput: false,
     order:[{
            model: 1,
            quanity: 10,
            date: 03
},
{
            model: N,
            quanity: N,
            date: N
},
{
            model: 10,
            quanity: 6,
            date: 12
          }]                                                                           
}
```

Как правильно перевести массив из **php**, в **js** массив "order"?

Comment: В вашем php массиве 3 значения в массиве, в js массиве - 4, уже что-то не сходится.

Comment: Извиняюсь, не убрал лишнее значение.

Comment: если вы сделаете так - `print_r(json_decode(result_json, true));` - увидите, какой структуры массив вам нужен. думаю, ничего сложного не понадобится

Comment: Не забывайте про `JSON_HEX_TAG` иначе замучаетесь с XSS бороться

Answer (score 1):

Проблема что в вашем массиве PHP нет ключей, но если предположить что значения идут в таком же порядке как и в JS массиве, конвертировать его можно вот так:

```
// Ваш исходный массив.
$credit=[
    ['Номер 1','10','03'],
    ['Номер N','N','N'],
    ['Номер 10','6','12']
];

// Готовим массив с нужным форматом.
$response = [
    'manualInput' => false,
    'order' => []
];

// Конвертируем массив в тот что хотим увидеть в JS.
foreach ($credit as $item) {
    $response['order'][] = [
        'model' => filter_var($item[0], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT),
        'quanity' => $item[1],
        'date' => $item[2]
    ];
}
?>

var credit_m_m = <?php echo json_encode($response); ?>;
```

Answer (score 1):

как то так видимо? Если у вас `N` это тестовые данные, а значения на самом деле целочисленные, то добавить а-ля `(int)$q`

```
$data = array_map(function($v){
            list($m, $q, $d) = $v;

            return [
                'model' => str_replace("Номер ", "", $m),
                'quantity' => $q,    // (int)$q
                'date' => $d,        // (int)$d
            ];
         }, $credit);

echo json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
```

альтернативный вариант записи тела функции обратного вызова

```
list($model, $quantity, $date) = $v;
$model =  str_replace("Номер ", "", $model);

return compact(['model', 'quantity', 'date']);
```